# How to get user input x times and print outside of loop

Tags: java

Im creating an easy blood transfusion game. I want to get the names and blood type then print them to the console. My code below does this but I cant print it to the console because the variable is inside the loop. How do I fix this?

```
  for ( int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
      {
        System.out.println("Type your full 
  name first: ");
        String donor = in.next();
        
        System.out.println("Now type your blood type: ");
        String bloodType = in.next();
    }
```

Comment: Create String arrays or lists for names and bloodtypes outside the loop or create a class Donor with properties name and bloodType and store your input in array / list creating a Donor object at each iteration

Answer (score 0):

If you will first gather all data and then print it out, you should temporarily store them somewhere. A good choice is string array or ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>(26); // 26 is the initial capacity
ArrayList<String> bloodTypes = new ArrayList(26);

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
  System.out.println("Type your full name first: ");
  String donor = in.next();
  names.add(donor);

  System.out.println("Now type your blood type: ");
  String bloodType = in.next();
  bloodTypes.add(bloodType);
}
```

Now you can iterate over the ArrayLists and print out your stored values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println("Blood type of " + names.get(i) + " is " + bloodTypes.get(i));
}
```